# adding new chart in ember chart project

Tags: ember.js, charts

my english is bad, apologise in advice.

I've to add a chart to the project  [addpear opensource ember charts](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-charts/overview).
I built the chart, and it works. Anyway i need to add it to the getting started page and at my version of library. how I can do that? wich (and where) files I have to add?

I have already the code of the component and it works, but is in another project. I would like to import that component in the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://emberjs.jsbin.com as a sandbox for developing it (you just need to add addepar's libraries).